# div content gets cut off

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser, border

I am facing a random CSS behaviour on Safari where at times, content in one of the divs gets cut off. It reappears if I somehow select the content using the mouse or by pressing Ctrl+A. Even modifying any of the CSS properties via the console or by resizing the window, makes the content appear. Here's the [before](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64935370/Screen%20Shot%202016-11-10%20at%2012.17.22%20AM.png) and [after](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64935370/Screen%20Shot%202016-11-10%20at%2012.17.59%20AM.png) comparison.

The hierarchy of elements is `threads-container` > `threads` > `thread` > `message`

It only happens to the last `message` container in a `thread` and happens only in some of the cases. I haven't been able to notice any pattern here. Also, if I remove `border-bottom` from `thread`, this behavior disappears. I am pasting the relevant CSS rules below:

```
div.main-container div.threads-container {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 0%;
  width: 39.58333%;
  background-color: #F6F7F9;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
div.main-container::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
div.main-container div.threads-container:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

div.main-container div.threads-container div.threads {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: calc(100% - 295px);
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

div.main-container div.threads-container div.threads div.thread {
  border-bottom: 1px Solid #e4e4e4;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  display: block; 
}

div.main-container div.threads-container div.threads div.thread div.message {
  color: #444444;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px; 
}
```

Is this a known bug in Safari or am I missing something here?

Comment: `solid` in `thread` rule as capital S, should be lowercase

Comment: Since you are using `float` and I can't see any clear of that, please post your HTML as well

Comment: @LGSon This is only the CSS I thought is relevant. The main-container is cleared, updated the question. No luck with lowercase s either.

Comment: Even if this is relevant CSS code, you should post some HTML that reproduces the problem. You will have more posibilities to get an answer if you do this.

Comment: you must have to give html or working fiddle with issue or we can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't a CSS issue. My HTML was laid out as:

```
<div class="threads">
    <div class="thread-options">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="threads">
        <div class="thread">
        ...
        </div>
        <div class="thread">
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The contents of `thread-options` and `threads` were generated asynchronously via Meteor. Whenever `threads` loaded before `thread-options`, it pushed `threads` down, probably confusing Safari and causing a rendering bug. Although I am not too sure what the exact problem was, but giving a height to `thread-options` even when there's no content fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really give enough info to find a real solution. I don't mean to be critical, but it seems like you started with well-formatted code, with one or two mistakes, and then messed it up trying to solve the problem. I tend to do this as well, and I usually end up with the same problem, plus a bunch of meaningless code.

It's going to be hard to find an answer to this without some HTML, but I can tell you that if you use a CSS pre-processor, like Sass, you will be able to visualize how you CSS interacts better, and it makes it a lot easier to write code like this properly.

PS- Even if you find an answer to this, you should still check out tools like Sass because they make CSS so much more useful.

Update: I just looked at you code a little bit closer. You have each selector written as 'div.class-name', and you don't really need the 'div' in there. I seriously doubt that this affecting anything, but if you don't need it, don't use it. Also, you should put commas in between each selector. That probably isn't doing anything either, but you can try that.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. The page is built using MeteorJS and React. The styles I pasted above are indeed generated using Sass. The reason I haven't posted HTML is that this is a random issue and I don't face it on all the pages. I am trying to create a JSFiddle to replicate it but I haven't succeeded yet. I was wondering if there is a common known issue in Safari which could point me in the right direction.